# fetch body message from gmail using imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am fetching mails from gmail. everything is ok i can fetch all the information. But my problem is while am fetching body message.

```
// fetching body message from gmail using php imap function    
imap_fetchbody($imap,$result,1.1);
```

I am getting asci code and some extra text but I only need the body message.

Comment: You really need to give us more than one line of code. 

Have you tried `imap_qprint` or `quoted_printable_decode` to see if they solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `BODYSTRUCTURE` and undo any `Content-Transport-Encoding` transformation which might apply to that particular message part.

Also, the `1.1` you're passing is *not* a decimal number, but a textual identifier using dots as a separator. The fact that it happens to work when you pass it as a floating point number is pure luck. Do not do that, use a proper string.